# Safari 14 freezing/slow loading and iOS 14.0.1 bad network performance

Tags: macos, iphone, network, safari, wifi

it's been 10 days since my MBP16 with macOS 10.15.7 (updated last week) and iPhone 6S with iOS 14.0.1 (updated as well 10 days ago) have problems with Safari. Slow loading, sometime the loading just freeze and to effectively load the webpage i need to tap reload a couple of time. I'm also experiencing general bad network performance on my iPhone.

On my macOS i've already enabled the Safari dev-tools in order to clear the cache.
On my iPhone i've tried to disable the WiFi private MAC address feature.

Internet connection is really good, other devices does not have any sort of problems.

What should i do starting from here in order to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: iOS 14.2 is out. Did it fix things for you?